# Can monsters attack multiple players on the monsters turn?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

I am playing betrayal house on the hill 3rd edition and a bit confused on how attacking works on the monsters turn.

On Pg 19 it says

> Monsters move differently than explorers, At the beginning of the monster turn, roll dice equal to the monster Speed. The result of that roll is the maximum number of tiles that monster can move that turn.

From my understanding, if the speed roll is 4 and there is up to 3 monsters on the board, ***each*** of the 3 monsters can move up to 4 tiles. So potentially you may be moving across 12 tiles in that same turn.

However it also says:

> Monsters may attack using normal attack rules; see page 15

Normal attack rules state:

> You may only attack once per turn.

But in the case of the monsters turn, does that apply to each individual monster or the turn as a whole.

e.g.

**OPTION 1: Applies to the turn as a whole**
Is it the case that only 1 of the 3 monsters on the board can attack a person.

**Option 2: Applies to each individual monster**
Is it the case all 3 monsters can attack a person.

If so can multiple monsters attack the same person? I feel like you can kill people rather too quickly like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each monster moves and attacks separately. On page 18, under the **How Monsters Work** section, it says:

> Each monster moves and takes all its actions before the next one[monster] goes.

This means that if a monster is capable, the traitor can attack a single survivor with each monster, possibly killing them. The survivor tome and traitor tome rules could have alternative rules that change what monsters do when they attack, so it does not always mean death. In my experience, if a traitor has multiple monsters running around, they are usually low attack and have a reasonable possibility of being defended against (or taking minimal damage).

---

The above comes from the 2nd Edition Rulebook, but since it's not noted under the 3rd edition "Important Changes" section, it's assumed to work the same.

Comment: Thanks, but the 3rd edition handbook doesn't mention this.

Comment: Are you using a different edition

Comment: The above is from the 2nd edition. There's no indication that these rules have changed, as there's no mention in the "Important Changes" section at the beginning of the 3rd edition rulebook on Page 5.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks